# RadAsyncUpload file validation fails

Tags: ajax, file-upload, telerik

I am using RadAsyncControl but my file validation is failing i have tried to track the issue [through this example](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/asyncupload/client-side-programming/onclientvalidationfailed) .. so my scenario says

> Wrong file size!

However i have set **MaxFileSize** property to **20971520**

and the file being chosen is 1kb .txt file (notepad)

Here's my code

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="rauEvidenceDocuments" runat="server" AllowedFileExtensions=".doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt. .rtf, .pages, .odt, .ppt, .pptx, .png" MultipleFileSelection="Automatic"
                       OnClientFileSelected="onClientFileSeleted" OnClientFileUploadFailed="OnClientFileUploadFailed" OnClientValidationFailed="validationFailed" RenderMode="Lightweight" MaxFileSize="20971520">

                   </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>

function validationFailed(radAsyncUpload, args) {
        var $row = $(args.get_row());
        var erorMessage = getErrorMessage(radAsyncUpload, args);
        var span = createError(erorMessage);
        $row.addClass("ruError");
        $row.append(span);
        //alert('validation failed');
    }

    function getErrorMessage(sender, args) {
        var fileExtention = args.get_fileName().substring(args.get_fileName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1, args.get_fileName().length);
        if (args.get_fileName().lastIndexOf('.') != -1) {//this checks if the extension is correct
            if (sender.get_allowedFileExtensions().indexOf(fileExtention) == -1) {
                return ("This file type is not supported.");
            }
            else {
                return ("This file exceeds the maximum allowed size" /*+ sender._maxFileSize()*/);
            }
        }
        else {
            return ("not correct extension.");
        }
    }

    function createError(erorMessage) {
        var input = '<span class="ruErrorMessage">' + erorMessage + ' </span>';
        return input;
    }
```

P.S. It is a multiselect control

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, so i found the issue it was giving me the wrong reason for validation. i had spaces in AllowedFileExtensions that's what was causing validation to fail.

So Cheers after wasting 2 hrs :)